# Query With Distinct Value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables `Tabel1` and `Table2`. My tables look something like this.

Table1 has three fields `Cust_Number, sales_org and Orders.`

Table 2 has fields by name `Cust_Number, sales_org, BU and Dist_Channel.`

Dist_Channel is missing in table1 hence I have to get the Distinct of Cust_Number and sales_org from TABLE 2 and then do a join with table1 to get the corresponding BU.

I was able to do it in MS access by creating one additional query to pull the distinct Numbers and then using that query in my final query.

Could anybody give some suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.cust_number, t2.bu, t2.dist_channel
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.cust_number = t2.cust_number
AND t1.sale_org = t2.sales_org
AND -- your actual criteria go here
```

Answer (score 0):

Cust_Number, sales_org, are common in both the table you can do this by left join

also first check distinct count of Cust_Number and sales_org in table 2 is same or not

```
SELECT Tabel1.Cust_Number, Tabel1.sales_org, Table2.BU FROM Tabel1 left JOIN Table2  ON Tabel1.Cust_Number = Table2.Cust_Number AND Tabel1.sales_org = Table2.sales_org
```

Comment: I agree with you yogesh but the problem is it has some duplicates means one customer shares same sales org for different Dist_Channel.To give example cust_Number 123 shares sale org 0015 twice for Dist_Channel 01 and 02. Hope you understood.

Comment: yes that can be possible because of that i told you to cross check distinct record

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple version :

```
SELECT t1.cust_number, t1.sales_org, t2.BU
FROM Tabel1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.cust_number= t2.cust_number AND t1.sales_org = t2.sales_org
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:-

```
SELECT tbl1.cust_number, tbl1.sales_org tbl2.bu, tbl2.dist_channel
FROM Table1 as tbl1, Table2 as tbl2
WHERE tbl1.cust_number = tbl2.cust_number
AND tbl1.sale_org = tbl2.sales_org
......
```

Answer (score 0):

Santhosa, as I understand the problem, it's that in Table2, you can have multiple rows that have the same customer number and sales org (but different dist_channels) so that a simple join to the table will multiply the number of rows coming out of Table1, which is not what you want. Instead, you want to use Table2 simply as a look up for the BU for a customer number and sales org, and we are *assuming* that there is a functional dependency from cust_number,sale_org --> BU, i.e. that for any given cust_number, sale_org pair in Table2, the BU is always the same.

If that assumption is true, then you can do the following:

```
SELECT tb1.cust_number, tb1.sales_org, tb2.bu
  FROM Table1 AS tb1
  JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT cust_number, sales_org, bu
      FROM Table2) AS tb2
    ON tb1.cust_number = tb2.cust_number
   AND tb1.sales_org = tb2.sales_org
```

But keep in mind that if you have multiple BUs for a given cust_number, sales_org pair, then this will still result in multiple rows being returned for a given cust_number, sales_org pair in Table1.

Comment: Thank you very much Burr.This is what i was looking for. very clear explanation.

Comment: One small clarification. Can i use left join here to get all the records form Table1.